# How to mill a spiral groove in aluminium without a milling machine or lathe

Tags: aluminum

I need to make my own lathe-like chuck out of aluminium for a one-off machine I'm making.

It will be self-centering so I need to make a spiral groove, 5mm deep, in a 10mm thick, 150mm diameter circular plate of aluminium. The grooves will be around 3-8mm wide, and spaced about the same.

I only have diy tools to do this - a mitre saw and pillar drill and the usual hand drills etc etc, no lathe or milling machine.

It it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: What diameter and thickness is the aluminum plate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Scribe out the groove you need to make first.
Use the drill to drill out the bulk of the material.

Finish the groove with a dremel. Since its aluminum you can also use a file and chisel to remove the material by hand.